# How to obtain the precision of BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal

I'm implementing a custom validator in my web application that can validate a `BigInteger` property of a bean. This property is mapped to a `Number(8, 0)` type of Oracle table.

Like `BigDecimal`, I don't see a method for `BigInteger` that can return the precision of a given number.

Basically, I'm first converting a `BigInteger` value to `BigDecimal` to obtain its precision like the following (It is just for a demonstration).

```
int minPrecision=1;
int maxPrecision=8;

BigInteger bigInteger=new BigInteger("12345");
BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(bigInteger, 0);

int precision=bigDecimal.precision();
boolean isValid=precision>=minPrecision && precision<=maxPrecision;

System.out.println(isValid+" : "+precision);
```

Does `BigInteger` provide a precise way to return the precision of its value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are mistaking with the scale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no precision method on a `BigInteger` because the concept of precision does not make sense for an Integer. `BigInteger` represents Integers of arbitrary size, as opposed to `BigDecimal` which represents exact decimal representations of floating point numbers and therefore have an associated precision.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert it to a string and count the number of characters:

```
...
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("12345678");
Integer numberOfDigits = bi.abs().toString().length();
boolean isValid=numberOfDigits>=minNumberOfDigits && numberOfDigits<=maxNumberOfDigits;
```

Comment: The sign `+` or `-` should be negligible for this.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Use `bi.abs()` to get the absolute value of the number.

Comment: Is this any better than the OP's method of using BigDecimal?  That way might be faster since it doesn't need to perform a binary->decimal conversion.